# Make background slide as a pill when clicked

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-shapes

I'm trying to do a small animation when I click my button.

I want the background to slide left and right in order to illustrate the user choice.

Here is my trial : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8a1pb9s7/)

```js
$(".test").click(function() {
  $(".test").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
div{
  list-style-type: none;
}
div a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cont {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.choice {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.choice div{
  width: 100px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #ff3232;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.choice .left {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, #b7d4e1 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: left bottom;
}
.choice .right {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #b7d4e1 50%, white 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
}
.choice .left.active {
  background-position: right bottom;
}
.choice .right.active {
  background-position: left bottom;
}
.choice div a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice">
  <div id="cont">
    <div class="test left active"><a href="#">Semaine</a>
        </div>
    <div class="test right"><a href="#">Mois</a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want that the background to stay pill-shapped all the slide long.

Comment: Well I prefer CSS only ... But if there's no choice ...

Comment: I think it is better to use rounded corner background image, instead of background color

Comment: I used to apply following solution for pure CSS animated toggle https://jsfiddle.net/a7tqxbq6/ But I'm not sure if this way you can put any text inside the toggle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make a **pill highlight the clicked element** without JS depending on your usecase.
The point is to use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and play with the [transition delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) so that the pill stays under the last focused link.

The pill is made with an extra span and `border-radius`. It is translated under the focused link:

```css
.choice{
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.link {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
}
.pill{
  position:absolute;
  left:16px; top:0;
  width:100px; height:100%;
  background:#B7D4E1;
  border-radius:20px;
  z-index:-1;
  transition: 9999s transform .2s ease-out;
}
.link:nth-child(2):focus ~ .pill{
  transform: translatex(132px);
  transition: transform .18s ease-out;
}
.link:nth-child(1):focus ~ .pill{
  transform: translatex(0px);
  transition: transform .18s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="choice">
  <a class="link" href="#">Semaine</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">Mois</a>
  <span class="pill"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Woaw exactly what I wanted ! You damn CSS god ! :D

Comment: The pill animation stopped when I clicked outside while the animation is going on, but nice trick :)

Comment: Yup saw that ... too bad :/

Comment: @Seba99 I speeded the animation up a little so it doesn't happen so much.

Comment: What if I have to use `<div>` instead of `<a>` ? ... I can't use `:focus` anymore ... That's why it still doesn't work ... :/

Comment: @Seba99 this approach relies on the use of the `<a>` tag. There would be another CSS only appraoch using `<input type="checkbox" />` and `<label>` but if you need to use `<div>` I am not aware of any CSS only solution.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/danvim/4jxc91dq/1/

I redid your structure, and used a 3d translation for the pill.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".choice button").click(function() {
     $(this).closest(".cont").removeClass("left right");
    if ($(this).hasClass("left")) {
     $(this).closest(".cont").addClass("left");
    } else {
     $(this).closest(".cont").addClass("right");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  background:#ccc;
}

span {
  list-style-type: none;
}

span a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cont {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.cont::before {
  content: " ";
  background:#B7D4E1;
  width: 100px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.choice {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.choice button {
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height:40px;
  border:0;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

.choice .cont.right::before {
  transform: translate3d(105px,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice">
  <div class="cont left">
    <button type="button" class="left">Semaine</button>
    <button type="button" class="right">Mois</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to convert radio forms to the element, you can try to extending the jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  $.fn.extend({
    makeRadio: function(){
      var temp = '<div class="choice"';
      var temp1 = '><div class="cont left">';
      var temp2 = '<button type="button" class="';
      var temp3 = '</button> ';
      var temp4 = '</div></div>';
      var $form = $(this);
      var $items = $form.children("input[type='radio']");
      var id = $form.attr("id");
      if ($items.length == 2) {
        var output = temp + ' id="' + id + '"' + temp1;
        for(var i = 0; i <2; i++) {
          output += temp2 + (i == 0 ? "left" : "right") + '" data-value="'+ $($items[i]).attr("value") + '">' + $($items[i]).attr("data-display") + temp3;
        }
        output += temp4;
        $form[0].outerHTML = output;
        console.log("#"+id+" button");
        $("#"+id+" button").click(function() {
         $(this).closest(".cont").removeClass("left right");
          if ($(this).hasClass("left")) {
           $(this).closest(".cont").addClass("left");
          } else {
           $(this).closest(".cont").addClass("right");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
  $("#convert").click(function(){$("#radios").makeRadio();})
  
  
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  background:#ccc;
}

span {
  list-style-type: none;
}

span a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cont {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.cont::before {
  content: " ";
  background:#B7D4E1;
  width: 100px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.choice {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.choice button {
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height:40px;
  border:0;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

.choice .cont.right::before {
  transform: translate3d(105px,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="convert">Convert to animated pill</button>
<form id="radios">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" data-display="Gentleman">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" data-display="Lady">
</form>
```